# How do I Render User Favorited Posts on User Profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a forum and am trying to display a list of posts that have been favorited by the current user in the `users/show.html.erb` view.

When I favorite a post however, then go to my user profile show page, I get the following error in my `app/views/favorites/_favorite.html.erb`:

```
NameError in Users#show

undefined local variable or method `post'

<% if favorite = current_user.favorite_for(post) %>
```

**Am I missing something in my `favorites_controller.rb` that is preventing it from saving, to then be rendered as a list? Or am I rendering it in the `users/show.html.erb` view improperly?**

*Here's my `favorites_controller.rb`:*

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in

  def create
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post)

    if favorite.save
      flash[:notice] = "Saved as favorite!"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Favorite failed to save."
    end
    redirect_to [post.topic, post]
  end

  def destroy
     post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     favorite = current_user.favorites.find(params[:id])

     if favorite.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Post unfavorited."
     else
       flash[:alert] = "Unfavoriting failed."
     end
       redirect_to [post.topic, post]
   end
end
```

*Here's how I rendered it in my `users/show.html.erb`:*

```
<h2>Favorites</h2>
   <%= render @user.favorites %>

   <h2>Posts</h2>
   <%= render @user.posts %>
```

Also tried this for `users/show.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Favorites</h2>
   <%= render partial: @user.favorites %>
```

*Here's my `favorites/_favorite.html.erb` (line #1 raised issue):*

```
<% if favorite = current_user.favorite_for(post) %>
 <%= link_to [post, favorite], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete do %>
   <i class="icon ion-ios-heart"> </i>&nbsp; Unfavorite
 <% end %>
<% else %>
 <%= link_to [post, Favorite.new], class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post do %>
   <i class="icon ion-ios-heart-outline"> </i>&nbsp; Favorite
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:
Tried a migration to AddUserToFavorites but ran into a migration error upon `rake db:migrate`

```
rails g migration AddUserToFavorites user:references
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have variable from controller accessible in view you have to use `@` (instance variable). So in your case update `FavoritesController` and use `@post = ...` instead of `post = ...`

Comment: Tried that in my view and controller maybe I'm misunderstanding something in the favorites_controller, I thought I would need a migration to add the favorites to the user to save them.  Still get the same error though with the @post:
```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post)
```

Comment: You have to replace post with @post in each line. In build method also